# SQL update column with previous row newly updated value

Tags: sql-server, update

Hope anyone who can shed some light.

I tried to bring the Week Ending Value to next week as Opening Stock value.

However, my update statement not working but returning me null. Eventually wrong Week Ending Value is computed due to Opening Stock value is not coming correctly.

No idea what went wrong ..

Appreciate your help.

[image]

This is the SQL I am having:

```
UPDATE s
SET WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING = ISNULL(OPENING_STOCK, 0) + CURR_WEEK_REMAINED,    
    OPENING_STOCK = (SELECT WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING 
                     FROM APP.ClosingSummary a
                     WHERE DATEADD(day, -7, s.WEEK_ENDING_DT) = a.WEEK_ENDING_DT 
                       AND s.OPERATOR = a.OPERATOR
                       AND s.PRODUCT_NAME = a.PRODUCT_NAME
                       AND s.PRODUCT_TYPE = a.PRODUCT_TYPE),
    PRE_WEDT = DATEADD(day, -7, s.WEEK_ENDING_DT)
FROM 
    APP.[ClosingSummary] s
```

Comment: I've updated your tags with `sql-server` but you should also update them to specify which version you're using too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use an updatable CTE along with window functions

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      Last_WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING = LAG(s.WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING) OVER (PARTITION BY s.OPERATOR, s.PRODUCT_NAME, s.PRODUCT_TYPE ORDER BY s.WEEK_ENDING_DT),
      Last_WEEK_ENDING_DT =      LAG(s.WEEK_ENDING_DT     ) OVER (PARTITION BY s.OPERATOR, s.PRODUCT_NAME, s.PRODUCT_TYPE ORDER BY s.WEEK_ENDING_DT)
    FROM APP.ClosingSummary s
)
UPDATE cte
SET WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING = ISNULL(Last_WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING, 0) + CURR_WEEK_REMAINED,
    OPENING_STOCK = Last_WEEK_ENDING_CLOSING,
    PRE_WEDT = Last_WEEK_ENDING_DT
;
```